# Select2 - Trigger open on click without library function for open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i'm using this library: https://select2.github.io

When you use this library and you want to force your select menu to open programmatically you run the following:

```
$('#fromAccIdx').select2('open');
```

and the select menu opens.

However if you run:

```
$('#fromAccIdx').click();
```

to simulate the click which is opening the menu it's not working like it's working with the mouse on this element.

I would like to know how can i open the select menu without using the `open()` function from the library itself.

Is it possible ?

Comment: inspect the element and find the classes and stuff it's applied to. Because when you click the select2, it's not actually hitting `fromAccIdx` but rather from its generated divs and such

Comment: Tried clicks on all possible elements and still select2 is not opening.

Comment: A demo would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you even need to open it without the built-in open function anyway?

Comment: This would be useful for automation bots. I have a set of repeated tasks I want to perform for testing, so I'm using an automation tool. I need to tell the automation tool what to click by id/DOM elements.

Answer (score -2):

Try this. it works.

```
 document.getElementById("fromAccIdx").click();
```

Instead of $('#fromAccIdx').click();

Comment: It's not triggering select2 to open.

Comment: Please use the appropriate id and remember to use that line of code inside the pageLoaded() function in javascript

Comment: I'm running this script directly into browsers console trying with all possible ids and select2 is not opening.

Comment: Can you give the blocks of code so i can try and post it here

Comment: what makes you think the two functions do anything different?

Comment: Postback matters in JQuery and Javascript. That is my problem i am trying to help you.